# How do I get Rails to use my memory cache instead of oging to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, memory, config

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 on my mac Sierra machine (PostGres 9.5).  I want to use a memory cache to cache some of my more common database queries.  For instance, here is a model with some cache methods …

```
class DistanceUnit < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.cached_find_by_id(id)
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{id}") do
      find_by_id(id)
    end
  end

  def self.cached_find_by_abbrev(abbrev)
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{abbrev}") do
      find_by_abbrev(abbrev)
    end
  end

end
```

I invoke the “cached_find_by_id” and “cached_find_by_abbrev” throughout my application.  Then in my ./config/environments/development.rb file I have

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  ...
  # Enable the Rails cache
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

But when I run my application locally, I notice SQL queries are run …

```
  DistanceUnit Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "distance_units".* FROM "distance_units" WHERE "distance_units"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]

…

  DistanceUnit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "distance_units".* FROM "distance_units" WHERE "distance_units"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
```

What else do I need to do to get Rails to use my cached methods?  Rails doesn't seem to be using my memory cache at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable perform_caching in development.rb thats:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Once done. Restart your console. Trigger the method. First time it will load from database and next time it will load from your memcache.

Also, I will recommend you using [identify_cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) gem by Shopify.